# Storing file names in an array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsfilemanager

I am looking for the code that will allow me to scan a folder in my project, and store all file names with a .jpg extension in an array. 
This is the code I have to scan the main folder of my xcode project, however how do I store the names of files found inside, within an array?

```
let filemanager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
let files = filemanager.enumeratorAtPath(NSHomeDirectory())
while let file = files?.nextObject() {
    // store all file names with extension (jpg) in array
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html

Comment: To be more specific regarding @boidkan ’s link see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/displayNameAtPath:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how it works. This function returns an array of all the files URLs in a directory *and all its subdirectories* from a given path.

```
func files(atPath: String) -> [NSURL] {
    var urls : [NSURL] = []
    let dirUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: atPath)
    if dirUrl != nil {
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let enumerator:NSDirectoryEnumerator? = fileManager.enumeratorAtURL(dirUrl!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: nil, errorHandler: nil)
        while let url = enumerator?.nextObject() as! NSURL? {
            if url.lastPathComponent == ".DS_Store" {
                continue
            }
            urls.append(url)
        }
    }
    return urls
}


let allFiles = files("/a/directory/somewhere")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let documentsDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL

let jpgFilesArray = (NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsDirectoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles | .SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants | .SkipsPackageDescendants, error: nil) as! [NSURL]).sorted{$0.lastPathComponent<$1.lastPathComponent}.filter{$0.pathExtension!.lowercaseString == "jpg"}
```

as a read-only computed property

```
var jpgFilesArray: [NSURL] {
    return (NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsDirectoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles | .SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants | .SkipsPackageDescendants, error: nil) as! [NSURL]).sorted{$0.lastPathComponent<$1.lastPathComponent}.filter{$0.pathExtension!.lowercaseString == "jpg"}
}
```